# How to round 0.0 to 0.00 in java?

Tags: java, decimal

I have used the following function

```
float val=0.0;
DecimalFormat toTheFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
float value=Float.valueOf(toTheFormat.format(val));
```

But its not suitable for all conditions like "0.0" still "0.0". Its not scale up to "0.00".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
DecimalFormat toTheFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

to round to 2 significant digits

Comment: `floats` cant be right padded with zeros - you need to use the output from `toTheFormat.format(val)` itself rather than `value`

Comment: Output from this method is in String. What if I need it in float?

Comment: Then you won't be able to right pad the fraction part of the as its a `float` - only a `String` can work

Answer (score 4):

try

```
DecimalFormat toTheFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Comment: Output from this method is in String. What if I need it in float?

Comment: You can do a conversion result

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is mistaken. *Rounding* is a numeric operation that takes a number x and returns another number y which approximates x and has the property that the decimal expansion has only so many digits. Example:

```
0.123 --> 0.12
```

But 0.0 and 0.00 are the exact same numbers, there is no point in rounding. What you (maybe) want is to format a number in a certain way on output. For this, see the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I use `DecimalFormat toTheFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");`

am getting output as **.00** not **0.00**

so this would be the correct code

`DecimalFormat toTheFormat = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");`